# Is there a way I can use Python to control the size and position of a Mac Window?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Generally I want to write a program to run in the background on Mac and when I push a keyboard shortcut, the current active window would be resized and positioned to the way I have set.

Something similar to the tool called SizeUp on Mac.  I think this shouldn't be difficult to implement and would be fun to take a try.

I would appreciate any resources you could point me to.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is off-topic here since it asks for resources and doesn't show any prior attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have an easier time attacking this in applescript.  Upon casual googling, [this link](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html) seems to have more or less what you want.  If you were more looking for a programming challenge in python, and less for a solution, then disregard this.

Comment: Thanks.  I do need this to be done in Python, but I have already found a Python-AppleScript package, so I think I'm good to start from here.  Thanks for your help.